# Why does "subject + kredas + accusative + adjective" make sense?

Tags: grammar

In an article from [TeoKajLibro](https://teokajlibroj.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/malsekreta-sekreto/#more-291), the following sentence appear

> *Multaj homoj kredas Irlandon katolika.*

I assume that this sentence is correct and means

- *Multaj homoj kredas ke Irlando estas katolika.*

How much does the word order matter here? And is this a trick specific to *kredas*?

Answer (score 12):

This is the so called *[predicative expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)* (*[predikativo](http://vortaro.net/#predikativo)*). It often represents a result of an action or is the complement of an opinion or idea (like with *kredi*). The adjective says something about either the subject or the object (both being in the *nominative case*). Here are some examples (and note how the English sentences have the same structure).

- I deem him **nice**. = *Mi opinias lin **afabla**.*
- We elected her **president**. = *Ni elektis ŝin **prezidento***.
- I arrived home **tired**. = *Mi alvenis hejme **laca**.*
- We painted the house **blue**. = *Ni farbis la domon **blua**.*
- Don't call me **an idiot**. = *Ne nomu min **idioto***.

If you use the same construction applied to an infinitive or a subordinate clause, then the predicative expression should be an adverb (like usual when you say something like “Helpi homojn estas grav**e**”).

- I find helping people **important**. = *Mi opinias helpi homojn **grave***.

The word order is not too important; you can swap it around a bit, but make sure that the predicative expression does not become a normal adjective/adverb, as that would change the meaning of the sentence:

- *La malsana knabino vekiĝis.* ≠ *La knabino vekiĝis **malsana**.*

In the first sentence the girl was already sick and just woke up. In the second sentence, the girl was perfectly fine when she went to bed, but woke up sick.

Sometimes it can be ambiguous whether the predicative expression applies to the subject or the object:

- I drove the guy home **drunk**. = *Mi hejmenveturigis la viron **ebria**.*

This could either mean that I, the driver, was drunk, or that I drove the guy home and when we arrived he was still drunk. Here you might be tempted wonder why we then not just put the predicative in the accusative case. That changes the meaning of the sentence, because it becomes an adjective:

- *Mi hejmenveturigis la viron ebrian.* = I drove the drunk guy home.

Comment: According to the PMEG, _predikativo_ is a “traditional term” used for other languages that is more aptly described in Esperanto as a _perverba priskribo_. See https://bertilow.com/pmeg/aldonoj/gramatika_vortareto.html for this definition and https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html for a discussion of these usages—including some where _-an_ is also allowed but causes a change in meaning, like “he painted the house red” vs. “he painted the red house”.

Comment: PMEG generally avoids using technical terminology, which I think is good. Nonetheless, I think the word _predikativo_ is still accurate for Esperanto. For instance, see [its definition in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#predikativo). PMEG says that _perverba priskribo_ traditionally is called _predikativo_. It in no way implies that the word is archaic and should be replaced with _perverba priskribo_; it just says that the term _perverba priskribo_ used in PMEG is in traditional—standard—linguistic grammar terms _predikativo_.

Comment: That’s a good point, but in the front-matter of PMEG, it’s explained why neologisms like _o-vortoj_ instead of the familiar terms like “nouns” are used—because they linguistically better fit than shoehorning in words from the linguistics of other languages. 

As a linguist, I think this matters because PIV was first published in 1970, just before modern cognitive linguistics was widely adopted. And analyzing Esperanto as a Romance language as PIV does can cause confusion. I think it does here.

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. I do think the usage of PMEG is very comprehensible and accessible to everyone, which is very good. I just have not gotten familiar with the exact terminology they use (I understand when reading PMEG, but I don't remember which terms mean what when I need to use them myself). Maybe I'm getting you wrong, but words like _predikativo_ don't apply just to Romance languages; I never got from PIV that it is trying to analyze Esperanto as if it were a Romance language. These words are general words from linguistics and apply to many languages, including Esperanto.

Comment: Yes, “predicative” is a cross-linguistic term, but it’s not a very well-defined one. In Esperanto, this construct has a form that we could always, in English, convert to an “as _adjective_” or “seemingly _adjective_” expression (depending on the aktionsart of the superordinate v-bar). Those are _not_ predicative expressions in English; they are subordinate adjectival predicates. True predicative expressions would be “he seems friendly”. Other Romance languages are similar. So a formalism is being used not just imprecisely to shoehorn it into Esperanto, but a bit inaccurately as well.

Comment: Hm yes, that is true. I am not a linguist, so I primarily just picked up the term from a professor of interlinguistics and Esperanto, and then went with the definition in PIV, and learned from there. But I did not realize certain English phrases were not considered predicatives, whereas the equivalent in Esperanto would be an predicative (with PIV's definition). Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Without using a lot of grammatical lingo here, we add adjectives to the end of sentences all the time - with *estas*.

- *Mi estas.* - I am (I exist.)
- *Mi estas laca.* - I am tired.

It also works with other verbs, including verbs with objects:

- *Mi ŝatas la panon varma.* - I like the bread (when it it is still) warm.

It can also be used to describe a change in state.

- *La suno kolorigas la nubojn ruĝaj.* - The sun is coloring the clouds red.

Finally, it can be used in examples like the one you presented.

- *Mi kredas tion.* - I belive that.
- *Mi kredas tion bona.* - I believe that is good.

You asked **why** it makes sense. My short answer to that is that we already do it with *estas*. (More theoretical answers are of course possible, but that is the answer that works for me.)

More detail here:

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html

Examples from the tekstaro:

- Mi ne estas tiel malhumila, ke mi kredas mian filinon neerarema.
- nun oni kredas la junulon murdita.
- kvalitoj, kiuj igas edzon feliĉa.
- [Felikso] lasis Paŭlon ligita.
- La prezidanto de la loka kongresa komitato anoncis la kongreson malfermita.
- li pro manko de novaj ideoj trovis tiun ĉi entreprenon akcelinda.
- Kruko trovas Banikon gimnastikanta.
- Ĉiu opinias avidon bona.
- Oni serĉas la realon kaj ĉiu opinias ŝajnon senvalora.”
- ĝi tenis homon sporta.
- 65 % da britoj taksas politikistojn nefidindaj.
- Oni juĝis la manovrojn finitaj.
- nun li havis la manojn ligitaj.
- Sur mia dorso plugis plugistoj, Faris siajn sulkojn longaj.
- Nomu viajn fratojn Mia popolo, kaj viajn fratinojn Kompatataj.
- ili plu ne povas teni la okulojn nefermitaj.
- ŝi lasis la boteletojn netuŝitaj.
- li trovas la tarifojn ekscesegaj.
- neniu konsiderus tiujn diplomojn seriozaj.
- [Ratoj] manĝis la homojn vivantaj.
- Mi vidas nur unu klarigon ebla.

Notice that often the semantic relationship of the words is often slightly different even if the endings follow the same pattern. There were dozens more examples like this, but I tried to include a variety.