# How do i say "Do you consider yourself happy?"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

> Vi konsideras vin feliĉa aŭ Vi konsideras vin feliĉan

I am rather confused what case to use between the nominative and the accusative. In Russian you use the instrumental: *ты считаешь себя счастлив-ым/ой*.
But since there's no instrumental in Esperanto, it's not possible. 
I'd appreciate it if you can explain me what to use and why.

Answer (score 8):

You use the nominative case here: *Ĉu vi konsideras vin feliĉa?*
Here *feliĉa* is a [predicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression), which is always expressed using the nominative case in Esperanto. There are more examples of this in PMEG: [Perverba priskribo de la subjekto](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/subjekto.html), [Perverba priskribo de la objekto](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html).

On the Esperanto Wikipedia page [predikativo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predikativo) is also an example with the word *konsideri*: “oni ne povas konsideri **neekzistantaj** tiujn faktojn”.

---

See also [this answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/why-does-subject-kredas-accusative-adjective-make-sense/1980#1980) for more examples and clarification.

Answer (score 5):

When adjectives and nouns agree (i.e. when they have the same -j and -n endings) they usually go together. Consider the following examples.

- *Ĉu vi konsideras vin feliĉa* - Do you consider yourself happy?
- *Ĉu vi konsideras vin feliĉan* - Do you consider a happy you?

In the second example, *feliĉan* is part of the object.

Another way to look at is is

- *Ĉu vi konsideras vin (esti) feliĉa* - Do you consider yourself (to be) happy?

Like other compliments of *esti*, *feliĉa* doesn't take an -n.

Comment: Question:  Couldn't both be correct? Feliĉa(n) could describe either the subject or the object, right?

Comment: No. Mi konsideras la novan ideon stulta -vs- mi konsideras la novan ideon stultan. The second one means you're considering the new stupid idea.

Comment: Mi konsideras la novan ideon has clearly two separate entities- "Mi" and "ideon" .  In the case of "Ĉu vi konsideras vin feliĉan?"  the two entities are the same person- vi(n). One is only different from the other grammatically, not in "reality". It seems a bit like arguing that happy is modifying yourself INSTEAD OF you in the English sentence- "Do you consider yourself happy?"  I would more tend to think that it is modifying you, but that is just my take on it.

Comment: I might be persuaded to say that "Ĉu vi konsideras vin feliĉan?" is an ill-formed sentence semantically, but grammatically it's the same grammatically as the other sentence. If you put an -n on *feliĉan* then it's part of the object.

Comment: My point is that feliĉan would be part of the object if it has the n on it, but it could also describe the subject in this case which happens to be the same person as the object, so the adjective could have the objective declension or not because it describes the same thing.  In the other sentence there are clearly two separate objects.

Comment: No. Esperanto doesn't work that way. Your point about *vi* and *vin* being the same person is like saying that "Do you consider a happy yourself" is good English because "you" and "yourself" are the same person. If you could find an example sentence from a model speaker or text that worked that way, we could discuss it further, but really the answer to your original question (could they both be correct) is no.

Comment: From my perspective it seems you want to subjugate meaning to grammar.  Grammar only serves to explain meaning.   You and Yourself in reality are the same thing, just different places grammatically.  The way I look at the sentence, the adjective could describe both the subject and the object

Comment: If you could find an example sentence from a model speaker or text that worked that way ...

Comment: I consider myself happy.  I and myself are in fact the same person.  They are different only grammatically, as one is the subject and the other is the object. So happy can modify either I or myself.  In English, there is no need to specify who it's describing, nor do I think it's  necessary in Esperanto.  I don't understand why you don't consider that a good example.

Comment: @Karlomanio The word ‘consider’ simply doesn't work that way. If you change the object to someone else, then clearly it described the object: “Do you consider him happy?” Here ‘happy’ obviously describes ‘him’ and not ‘you’. So, no, it cannot describe the subject. From the New Oxford dictionary: “regard (someone or something) as having a specified quality”. So the quality (in the example ‘happy’) always relates to the object, not the subject. In Esperanto *konsideri* works the same way in this context.

Comment: @Karlomanio - I meant you should find an example of someone saying this in Esperanto. It should be an example written by someone else (not you or me) in a text which is considered by a large number of Esperanto speakers to be good Esperanto. You won't find it because this is not how Esperanto works.