# Akuzativo: ĉu tajperaro, aŭ mia propra miskompreno?

Tags: accusative

Mi legis en romano la jenan frazon:

"La avino de mia patro rekonstruis la domaron pli proksime al la vilaĝo, kie estis malpli da risko, ke ĝi fariĝos celo de nova rabatako."

Kial ne "celon" anstataŭ "celo"?

Ĉu mi miskomprenas la ĝustan uzadon de la akuzativa finaĵo?

Answer (score 7):

Kelkaj verboj ne havas rektan objekton (en akuzativo) kiel predikato, sed "predikativon": frazparton, kiu priskribas la subjekton aŭ la objekton pere de la predikato. Iuj el ĉi tiaj verboj estas:

- esti
- iĝi
- **fariĝi**
- ŝajni
- montriĝi
- nomiĝi

Por subjekta predikativo, oni uzu nominativon.

Vidu [Nominativo → Predikativo](https://lernu.net/eo/gramatiko/nominativo#predikativo) en la gramatika sekcio de Lernu.net kaj la rilatan demandon [Why does "subject + kredas + accusative + adjective" make sense?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/1978/1576).

Comment: Ankaŭ por objekta predikativo oni uzu nominativon. Vidu [ĉi tiun respondon al rilata demando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/1980/25). Estas bone mencii, ke la predikativo ne estas limigita al nur tiuj listigitaj verboj, nek al predikato: _la bebo naskiĝis sana_; _li provas aspekti bela_.

Comment: Dankon, @Joffysloffy. Mi iom redaktis la respondon. Bonvolu pli redakti ĝin aŭ skribi vian propran respondon.

Comment: Ĉi tiel ĝi estas tute bona laŭ mi :).

Comment: Bone, dankon. :-)

Comment: Tiu iom komplika formulado celas al du formoj: `tio estas bona solvo` kaj `mi opinias tion bona solvo`.